Is hourly climate forecast data for the coming hour?
Is hourly climate forecast data, for example NOAA GFS model datafiles, for the coming hour, e.g. the 11 AM datafile is for the time from 11:00 to 11:59 AM?
This is what I have been assuming.  However, I am having doubts because I found documentation regarding measured data that states "data value will be for the hour ending at the time specified" (https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/pub/data/cdo/documentation/PRECIP_HLY_documentation.pdf).  While this makes sense for measured data, I could not find anything definitive for forecast data.
Is there documentation that can confirm that hourly forecast datafiles are for the coming hour?
EDIT: The answer is that forecast data files represent instantaneous values at the hour specified, and measured data files represent time-averaged values up to the hour.

Welcome to SO. This is not a question about programming. The question is about NOAA documentation, which in fact seems pretty clearly written, not coding

Thanks for the feedback @RobertWilson.  I will close this post.

The answer is that forecast data files represent instantaneous values at the hour specified, and measured data files represent time-averaged values up to the hour.
